# Merging SVG multiple paths together in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, svg, optimization

I'm working on a whiteboard app using SVG in react/node where drawn content will be saved in a db for further use. I want to be able to convert multiple paths into a single one because if the canvas is continually drawn on, some paths will end up irrelevant as they would be covered by other paths layered on top. That's why it doesn't make sense to me to be saving every single path to the db; using up more space and a longer save/load time. Is there a way in JS to optimize my SVG to make it server friendly?

Comment: I guess that would involve writing your own svg renderer in order to be able to detect which elements are hidden or not. But one easy way to make your svg server friendly is to gzip it.

Comment: Browsers already contain such culling optimisations.